Segmentation Fault While Trying to Print a Pascal Triangle using Recursion
So I am a newbie in terms of dsa and following a dsa course but before I watch the video I first try it on my own and I am getting this error "Exception has occurred. Segmentation fault". I tried to google it but didn't understand properly so asking here.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int fact(int num){
    if(num==1){
        return 1;
    }
    return num * (fact(num-1));
}

int main(){
    cout<<"Enter a Number!\n";
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int iCj;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
            iCj = fact(i)/(fact(j) * (fact(i-j)));
            cout<<"\n"<<iCj<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

Tried to add a extra line of code i.e "if (num==0){return 0;}" but this is not helping.
The program fully get executed only when the value for variable 'n' is 0. Anything >0 leads to segmentation fault.

In math 0! = 1 --> change the if inside fact to if(num<=1) and things should improve. Your current code would immediately call fact(0) which then recurses forever and runs into a stack overflow.

If n > 0 the first loop iteration calls fact(0) which recurses forever (which, on your target system, leads to a segmentation fault).   If n is zero, then the outer loop body is not entered, so fact() is never called.

So I am a newbie in terms of dsa -- The abbreviation dsa has a specific meaning on StackOverflow, meaning Digital Signature Algorithm.  Second, I tried to google it but didn't understand properly so asking here. -- You should be using (or learn to use) a debugger.

Welcome to StackOverflow - You're experiencing a stack overflow! :-)
Your recursive function checks for the base case of n == 1 and calls itself with an input value of n-1 otherwise.
But, you call it in your first main function loop iteration with an argument of 0, meaning it generates the call chain:
fact(0) -> 0 * fact(-1) -> 0 * -1 * fact(-2) -> 0 * -1 * -2 * fact(-3) -> ...
This goes on for a really long time.
Each call to a function creates a context called a Stack Frame, and returning from a function destroys that context again. In your case, fact calls itself so often that the amount of stack frames exceeds the limit the operating system puts on it, so the system kills your process due to a memory access violation called a segmentation fault.
Your bug is the check for n == 1: It should check for n <= 1 instead (and while you're at it, you might also want to throw in an assert(n >= 0); too, so your factorial function doesn't accept undefined negative inputs).

Yes I changed the if condition to num==0 and also changed the return type of fact function to "long long" and int iCj to long long iCj. So now it works till the input is >=66 anything greater than that and it throws an arithmetic expression exception. What concept should I learn to accept input for num even larger ?

@TheSelfProclaimedGenius13 there are libraries that deal with large numbers, or even with arbitrarily large numbers. Google big integer library, but at your level I wouldn't look into that until you have more C knowledge.

@TheSelfProclaimedGenius13 I remember once upon a time, calling the recursive factorial for 6 would cause stack overflow; those days are long gone. But even 64 bit integer is too small for 21!; Anything larger overflows the integer value. If 64 low order bits go 0 in the divisor, the program goes UB. So use std::uint64_t and limit the input to less than 22. Implementation of traingle doesn't need factorial function  any how. let iCj=1; in the outer loop, and multiply by (i+1-j) then divide by j in the inner loop; youll need to skip the division for j==0`.

For j==0, just print 1.
